# how to encrypt plist file either common crypto or security transforms?

Tags: ios, encryption, plist

I have data in plists in an iPhone app that I want to encrypt.
Reading Apple Common Crypto and Security Transformations documents.

Any suggestions on best way to encrypt the plists (common vs transforms)?

Additional security related question...(yes nothing is 100% secure)...
If a method uses a proprietary algorithm and someone puts the app through something like class-dump-z will they be able to see the algorithm?

Comment: Security through obscurity is bad. If someone dumps the code, the key has to be in there somewhere, whether you use common crypt or a proprietary algorithm.

Comment: Possibly store the encryption key in the Keychain, so its not in the code?

Comment: That would work if you encrypt them with a random key on first run. But, then they live unencrypted in the original code bundle, which someone could download and dump. There isn't really a good way to do this.